# TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined at "offset().top"

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, anchor, prototype

I'm trying to get the menu to scroll to an anchor and I got the following error:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

The code is below:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var target = this.hash;
            $target = $(target);

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
            }, 300, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
            });
        });
     });
```

When I click the link the page goes to the section but the slow effect doesn't play.

Can someone tell me whats wrong?

I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 which is loaded from google api. The menu runs prototype.

The website is follow: http://concursosomosluces.com/

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `this.hash` is not an element. May be you want `var $target = $(this);`

Comment: @Vega, it looks like OP is trying to use the hash as an ID selector

Comment: @Vega I made the replace but:"Uncaught ReferenceError: target is not defined"

Comment: @AndrésPosadaLlano Could you narrow down just the part of the issue and post it somewhere? or Post the relevant html code.

Comment: @Vega Thanks. When I click the link, appears: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

$('html, body').stop().animate({
'scrollTop': $target.offset().top

Html code:

<ul id="menuPushCont">
   <li><a href="#home">Inicio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#part">Cómo participar</a></li>
   <li><a href="#que-es">Qué es?</a></li>
   <li><a href="#concurso">Concurso</a></li>
   <li><a href="#criterios">Criterios de evaluación</a></li>
   <li><a href="#jurados">Jurados</a></li>
   <li><a href="#premiacion">Premiación</a></li>
   <li><a href="#premios">Los premios</a></li>
</ul>

Comment: ¿Should I use a smooth scroll developed with Prototype? Thank you!!